# My logs contain a SQL query, and the part after query : is getting printed separately on different lines on opensearch. I have attached log in desc

Tags: kubernetes, opensearch

```
2023-08-18 13:49:25    ;GMT+02:00   ;S0NS        ;Quhgfjaskafj    ;                ;1unknownUser, transaction id: _1235982_11702, query engine type: XYZ_LIST, timestamp: 2023-08-18 13:49:25:986, query:
```

This is the log I am getting, and the SQL query after "query :" is getting printed separately on different lines on opensearch. What changes I should do in fluentd to get the complete log including  the query?
I tried using the multiline fluend plugin as atatched below, but I am still getting the SQL query in multiple line of logs.

```html
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24284
  bind 0.0.0.0
  @label @INPUT

  <parse>
    @type multiline
    format_firstline /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/
    format1 /^(?<log>.*\n)/
    format2 /^\s*;[^\n]*query:/
    match_after true
  </parse>
</source>
```